# Change style height of div with JavaScriptExecutor Selenium Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I have 'WebElement div' which represent my div:

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 100px;">
```

I try to change height of my div like this:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

WebElement div = ...;

js.executeScript("document[0].style.height = '200px'", div);
```

but doesn't work.

And this is exception I get:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
```

How I can change height of my div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the javascript code is wrong here. It should be `arguments[0]` instead of `document[0]`.

Please change/replace the following line

```
js.executeScript("document[0].style.height = '200px'", div);
```

with the line

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.height = '200px'", div);
```

Answer (score 3):

`document` wouldn't be a valid selector here. You would want to do something like `document.querySelector("div").style.height = "200px"`

Answer (score 3):

You are passing div tag (`WebElement`) as an argument to `executeScript` method which will be passed on to `JavaScript` function to be executed, as per this [doc](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-).

So, you need to use below code (`arguments[0]`- first argument, instead of `document[0]`):

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

WebElement div = ...;

js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.height = '200px'", div);
```